# Using electron, how can I allow the user to select a file and then pass the filename along with its full file path?

Tags: path, electron

Currently, I have the following html for selecting the file:

```js
 <label for='input-file'>Select a file</label>
 <input type='file' id='input-file', name='input-file'>
```

The input is passed to this javascript function:

```js
$('#input-file').on('change', (e)=> {
  let script = e.target.value;
  window.location.href = `/convert?script=${script}`;
});
```

Let's say the user selects C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\filmfox\scripts\test.fdx
in the js function, this is picked up as C:\fakepath\test.fdx, which is down to Chrome being over-protective (as we all know). I, of course, need the full path name.

Another function reads in the file (or not at the moment) using fs.readfile. I have no problem with changing this to some sort of client-side call if that's part of the solution.

FWIW, this is what my main.js file looks like:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');
const expressApp = require('./express-app/app');
const PORT = 3000;

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        fullscreen: true, // Set fullscreen to true
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            preload: __dirname + '/preload.js'
        }
    });

    // Load the Express app in the main window
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');

    // Create the menu
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: 'X', click: () => app.quit(),
        },
    ]);

    // Set the menu
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}

expressApp.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Express server is running on port 3000');
    app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

Comment: You may want to look into handling this by using the electron's native open file dialog: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options